# How to loop through Beautiful Soup elements to get attribute values

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I need to iterate over Beautiful Soup elements and get the attribute values:
For a XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Document>
    <Page x1="71" y1="120" x2="527" y2="765" type="page" chunkCount="25"
        pageNumber="1" wordCount="172">
        <Chunk x1="206" y1="120" x2="388" y2="144" type="unclassified">
            <Word x1="206" y1="120" x2="214" y2="144" font="Times-Roman" style="font-size:22pt">K</Word>
            <Word x1="226" y1="120" x2="234" y2="144" font="Times-Roman" style="font-size:22pt">O</Word>
        </Chunk>
     </Page>
</Document>
```

I would like to get the x1 values of the "Word" elements (206,226).
Help much appriciated!

EDIT:
I have tried:

```
for i in soup.page.chunk:
    i.word['x1']
```

that returns an error:

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 473, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'word'
```

while:

```
soup.page.chunk.word['x1']
```

works correctly...and:

```
for i in soup.page.chunk:
    i.findNext(text=True)
```

gets the text form the element.

Comment: edited the question with my failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work although not that elegant:

```
for word in soup.page.chunk.find_all('word'):
    print word['x1']
```

Nested find_all's also should work. But probably it's better to use css-like select (soupselect or from lxml).

Basically if I'm not mistaken `soup.page.chunk` is a node, soup tag. So if you want iteration you have to call find_all.

upd. different approach could be `find_all('word')` and then filter on conditions like `word.parent.name == 'smth'`

[!] in BeautifulSoup3 (not bs4) it should be `findAll` instead of `find_all`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not sure if this has changed in BS4, but in BS3 it should be "findAll".

Comment: @root: Indeed. :) bs4 offers somewhat weirdly both camel- and snake- named versions.